# How can i obtain event Valuechanged on manually entered controls?

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, event-handling

The event ValueChanged is avaible only if I drag and the control from toolbox item .
for example if i add a control manually :

Dim combobox = New System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox

In the menu event doesn't appears the event Valuechanged for the combobox that i have entered manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register the event handler yourself:

```
Dim combobox = New ComboBox()
AddHandler combobox.SelectedValueChanged, AddressOf combobox_SelectedValueChanged

Sub combobox_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    '...
End Sub
```